# Div placed using JavaScript are not displayed in the correct place

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with inserting a specific element using JavaScript.

First of all, my website structure is as follows.

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
<p id="billing_email_field">..</p>
<p id="billing_country_field">..</p>
<p id="billing_first_name_field">..</p>
<p id="billing_postcode_find_field">..</p>
<p id="billing_address_1_field">....</p>
</div>
```

I want to add a Wrap element above the `billing_address_1_field` element.

So I put the Warp element using the code below.

```
<script>
    //빌링에 wrap 엘리멘트 추가
    const parent = document.querySelector('#woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper');
    const billingField1 = document.querySelector('#billing_address_1_field');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrap');
    newDiv.style.cssText = 'display:black;width:100%;margin:5px 0;';

   parent.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
</script>
```

However, when using this code, the warp will be placed on top of the div element.

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
        <div class="wrap"></div>
        <p id="billing_email_field">..</p>
        <p id="billing_country_field">..</p>
        <p id="billing_first_name_field">..</p>
        <p id="billing_postcode_find_field">..</p>
        <p id="billing_address_1_field">....</p>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me how i can solve this problem?

I'd like to use insertBefore instead of prepend due to compatibility issues with IE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On your script please add a dot(.) instead of hash(#) :

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper');
```

hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Hello. I misspelled # in this post. I put . on the website correctly and it still doesn't solve the problem.
The code seems fine, but is there anything else I should check on this issue?

Comment: I am not sure where you want to put the new div. If its on the last another line will be added like: parent.insertBefore(billingField1,newDiv);  Or you can just send a link with your work I can find out the problem.